Is there a way to select all elements of class ("btn") whose parents are of class ("seat") using javaScript and change it's background color?
I am trying to implement a bus seat layout. I want seats to change it's background color when clicked. The seats are bootstrap radio buttons with class='seat' and labels with class='btn'.
I have tried to write a javascript code but I don't seem to get .style attribute, vs code autocomplete a different attribute. Here is part of my javascript code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('.seat .btn').forEach(seat=>{
        seat.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            seat.computedStyleMap
        })
    })
})

the seat element:
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 seat px-1 justify-content-end d-flex">
   <input type="radio" class="btn-check mx-1" name="seat" id="C1">
   <label class="btn" for="C1"><i class="bi bi-layout-sidebar-inset-reverse"></i>C1</label>
</div>

I have tried document.querySelector(".seat > .btn").forEach... I still get the same auto complete which is "seat.computedStyleMap". I was expecting to have "seat.style.backgroundColor = red".

Is this a JavaScript problem or a VS Code problem?  What happens when you write the code you want to write, regardless of the auto-complete suggestions?

The selector .seat .btn selects the "btn" elements, not the "seat" elements.

@David I have tried to write the but once I write .style.backgr... it goes straight to autocomplete. So I thought may be there is a problem on how I select the element.

@Pointy thank you for your comment. The issue is that I have other elements of class btn that I don't want to be affected by the event; I only want btns that a children of seat(s).

@Balup: So you’re describing a problem with VS Code, not with JavaScript?  And you’re claiming that VS Code is somehow preventing you from finishing this line of code?  Please update the question to elaborate on the problem you’re trying to describe.  Currently it appears that you’re asking about something in the code itself, which is misleading.

@David Thank you for your comment. My primary goal is to style the seats with JS; I didn't think that VS code was malfunctioning, I thought my code was the reason. It's like trying to add a 'required' attribute in h1 element; that is why my question is based on how to select an element. If you still find think the question is misleading then I will change it ASAP, sir.

Just use CSS


[name=seat]:checked + label {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: white !important; 
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 seat px-1 justify-content-end d-flex">
   <input type="radio" class="btn-check mx-1" name="seat" id="C1">
   <label class="btn" for="C1"><i class="bi bi-layout-sidebar-inset-reverse"></i>C1</label>
   <input type="radio" class="btn-check mx-1" name="seat" id="C2">
   <label class="btn" for="C2"><i class="bi bi-layout-sidebar-inset-reverse"></i>C2</label>
</div>



